# Change Image on select option (other possibility then mine)

Tags: javascript, html

So I have my image

```
<img class="box_model" id="imageToSwap" src="img/woman.jpg" />
```

and my list of options

```
<option value="img/woman.jpg">Woman</option>
<option value="img/man.jpg">Male</option>
```

and a few lines javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function swapImage(){
var image = document.getElementById("imageToSwap");
var dropd = document.getElementById("se");
image.src = dropd.value;    
};
</script>
```

But since I want to use the value for another function, I want to do it antoher way. Does anyone have a method, where the value will not get touched?

Thanks!

Comment: You want to use a `select` element to do two separate things, one of which can't use the `select` element's `option`s?

Comment: I cut it out, there is nothing special on it ...

Comment: No, but I want to use a value in php from this options, so I need to find another way. So I want that the value looks like value="1" and not the url anymore, but the image should also change. So thats my issue.. finding another way to change the image when an option is taken without using the value for this task ..

Answer (score 0):

You can either use html5 attributes like data-url in your options or you can store somewhere a map where you can find the corresponding url for the selected value.